# How to make eclipse to run from dash

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, eclipse

I have ubuntu 14.04 today i just installed eclipse from software center.
It was installed properly, and it showed icon of eclipse in dash ,but i when i click to open it from dash it wont open, but opens successfully from terminal. Please help me to make it run from launcher.

Comment: which command do you use to run eclipse from terminal?

Comment: I just type
eclipse in terminal and it runs

Comment: what is the output of `which eclipse`?

Comment: It starts eclipse

Comment: it should return something like `/usr/bin/eclipse` or similar...

Comment: Thank you for your response, but now my eclipse is working properly.
My problem is solved

Comment: If you know, what the problem was, you can write an answer about it and accept it, so others know, your question is solved

Answer (score 0):

Actually i had eclipse installed along with android studio. There wasn't any need of android studio so i removed it and then afterwards eclipse was starting from dash.